# Java doesn't support multiple inheritance but implicitly every class in java extends Object and allows one more

Tags: java

In Java, all classes are extending Object class implicitly , on top of that at max only one class can be inherited.
So is it like , implicitly Java is allowing us to extend 2 classes or it is some other logic Java is following?

Comment: thats not limited to 2 if you closely look. It can be infinetely many but that does not change that you can extend only one class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your class that extends that other class, but it extends Object, too, so you're still in one line of inheritance, not two.

Answer (score 13):

No. In Java, a class can only inherit from one class and by default this is the Object class that you refer to. We can however specify a different class to inherit from (using the 'extends' keyword). However, this parent class will itself have a parent class and so on until ultimately we get back to the Object class. Perhaps an example will help:

```
class Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}

class Tiger extends Cat {
}
```

In the above example Tiger inherits from Cat which inherits from Animal which (by default) inherits from Object.

Hope this clears things up a touch.

Answer (score 7):

No. You're allowed to extend only one class, but this class can itself extend another one. If you don't specify any superclass in the extends clause, you extend from Object directly. If you specify a class in the extends clause, you extend from this class, which extends its own superclass, etc., until Object.

Answer (score 4):

Every Java class that does not specify an extension automatically extends Object.  Therefore, if you extend from another class there will be some endpoint extension that does not extend a class and defaults to Object.  This causes every class to transitively extend Object.

Answer (score 3):

"No, this is a misunderstanding of implicit object inheritance. Every Java class is ultimately descended from the Object superclass, whether there is an extends Object statement or not. If you extend an Application Programming Interface (API) class, the Object inheritance is passed down through that immediate superclass, not from the superclass and  the Object class too. Implicit inheritance from the Object  class descends through a single line of parent classes to ensure all user defined classes have the standard toString(), equals()  and hashCode() methods. "

Others answers here  - [Inheritance in java and Superclasses(Object, Class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452461/inheritance-in-java-and-superclassesobject-class)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly....
You can inherit from one class at a time, but nothing prevent this class from having a parent itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyExamples
{
    public class Object
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public void A1()
        {
        }
    }
    public class B : Object
    {
        public void B1()
        {
        }
    }

    public class D : B
    {
        public void D1()
        {
            D obj = new D();
            obj.A1();
        }
    }
}
```

//This is something like this if a class extends another class then i am thinking that it will not extend object class anymore
//but the parent class will be implementing object class...and this is equivalent to multilevel inheritance
//like  D extends B but B doesnt extend object class anymore
//and B by default extends object class. So if we create an object of D then we can access object class too

Answer (score 0):

class A          *//internally extends Object Class*

{

}

public class B extends A  *//JVM wont extend object class here because A already extends Object*

{

}

Comment: Can you offer a bit of explanation about what you're doing here?

Comment: 1, Object class is Super class of every class

Comment: Object class is Super class of every class but the relationship is multilevel not multiple. Here Class A does not inherit any class so internally Object class inherited to Class A, but Class B is extending Class A so another class(Object Class) can not be extended here. But still Object Class is super class of Class B because Class A internally extends Object class.    (Object---->A----->B)