# Java classes doesn't involve in multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

In java they are saying that class can not be inherited by multiple super classes. Only can be one. See this code,

**Animal.java**

```
public class Animal {   }
```

**Dog.java**

```
public class Dog extends Animal{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Animal animal = new Animal();
    Dog bulldog = new Dog();
    Dog rottweiler = new Dog();



    if (bulldog.equals(rottweiler)) {

        System.out.println("animal == bulldog");

    }else {

        System.out.println("animal != bulldog");
    }

}    }
```

Hear We can see that Dog class is inheriting from Animal. But I am using equals method which belongs to **Object** class in java. In SCJP book they are saying that each and every class in java is a subclass of Object class. Yes..! That is why I am able to use methods like equals in Dog class. Then my question is, aren't we unknowingly using multiple inheritance in java? Why because we are inheriting from Object and Animal classes to Dog class?

Comment: `Object --> Animal --> Dog`. This is the hierarchy. I don't see multiple inheritance here. Its only multi-level.

Comment: Nope! `Dog` inherits from `Animal`; `Animal` inherits from `Object`. That's single inheritance. The inheritance "cascades" in a way, but that is not multiple inheritance.

Comment: [Here the answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790435/java-doesnt-support-multiple-inheritance-but-implicitly-every-class-in-java-ext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `Animal` extends `Object`; and `Dog` extends `Animal`. Hence, it is single inheritance anyways.

The `equals()` method is defined in `Object`, and it becomes accessible to `Dog` **via** `Animal`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Java supports multi-level inheritance but not multiple inheritance.

- multi-level inheritance : C extends B, B extends A (legal)
- multiple inheritance : C extends B,A (not legal)

So in your case `Dog` extends `Animal` and `Animal` extends `Object`, which is legal.

Answer (score 0):

Every class in Java (except `Object`) has exactly one *immediate* superclass.  If you had a class called `Rottweiler` in your example, then the immediate superclass of `Rottweiler` would be `Dog`, the immediate superclass of `Dog` would be `Animal` and the immediate superclass of `Animal` would be `Object`.  Although `Rottweiler` has three superclasses (`Dog`, `Animal` and `Object`), and can inherit members from all three of those, it only has one *immediate* superclass.

If we had multiple inheritance, we'd be able to do things like define `Dog` to extend both `Animal` and `Companion`.  But we can't do that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

That is called "Multilevel inheritence" not multiple inheritence.

Consider the examples below:

Example 1:

```
class Foo { // Here you haven't specified any extends, so internally it will be
            // from Object class
}
```

Example 2:

```
class Bar extends Foo { //Here you have Foo as parent class
                        //Now Bar has all of the methods which are accessible
                        //from Foo as well as Object which is a parent of your
                        //class "Foo"

}
```

This is what you are assuming:

```
class Bar extends Foo,Object { //No this is not how it works

}
```

Hope it helps you.