# Multiple inheritance is restricted in java?

Tags: java, oop

Theoretically, multiple inheritance is restricted in java but `java.lang.Object` class implicitly extended to *every class*. Need clear explanation about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790435/java-doesnt-support-multiple-inheritance-but-implicitly-every-class-in-java-ext

Comment: Multiple inheritance means: one class extends several other classes. That's not allowed in Java. But that doesn't mean that multiple classes can't extend the same class. i.e. a father has many children, but a child has only one father.

Comment: and that's why interface came.

Comment: `if (class not extends any class different of Object) then extends Object else extends the other class`

Comment: Please anyone explain how to remove duplicate on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Its multilevel inheritance not multiple inheritance.

If your class is not extended by another class then it's extends `java.lang.Object` class.

But If your class is extends another class then that another class is not having any super class that class get extend by `java.lang.Object` class not your class.

Suppose initially you have class `A`

```
class A{

}
```

It not having any super class so it extends `java.lang.Object` class.

But

```
class B{

}

class A extends B{

}
```

In this scenario your class is get extends by class `B` and `B` is not extending another class so at this point `B` will extend `java.lang.Object` class.

`java.lang.Object` class is super class means when your custom super class will end at that time your super class extends `java.lang.Object` class.

Answer (score 1):

Not every class directly inherits/extends `Object` class.

If a class don't extend any other classes, then it directly extend `Object` class in java.

Answer (score 0):

There simply is no multiple inheritance.

All classes inherit either directly from `Object` (if no base class is specified) or do so indirectly by virtue of the base class itself inheriting (directly or indirectly) from `Object`.  All instances only contain a single copy of any fields owned by their parents.

Instead of multiple inheritance, Java relies on *Interfaces* to allow a class to declare that it offers a set of functionality, and each class may `implement` multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, in Java, a subclass cannot inherit multiple superclasses (you would use interfaces instead)

However, a superclass can be inherited by multiple subclasses (such as the `Object` example)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is a feature of some object-oriented computer programming languages in which an object or class can inherit characteristics and features from more than one parent object or parent class.
Check : [Multiple Inheritance - Wiki](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMultiple_inheritance&ei=ApS_VPP5AsezmAXSvIAw&usg=AFQjCNGeYvnz6v_b_j1invOXH22XWEEBiQ&sig2=7DjuaO5_77H_OgtcMfm_AQ&bvm=bv.83829542,d.dGY)

Object class : Many classes inherit it; it doesnt inherit from many classes.

You were getting the definition of multiple inheritance mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in how you see it. As *JB Nizet* says, it is *multi-level* inheritance and not *multiple* inheritance.

Example :

If you look at [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), then it doesn't *directly* extend `Object` . It *implicitly* gets the properties of Object from its parent's parent's parent i.e, [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) - which extends `Object`

So, only the *first level parent classes* extend Object. The Subclasses of these *first level classes* extend *Object* implitly because their parents extend Object.