# Does Java not support multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets us take instances of two classes

```
public abstract class Shapes
{
      public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

}

public class Rectangle extends Shapes
{
     public void draw(Graphics g)
     {
          //implementation of the method 
     }
}
```

Here the class `Rectangle` has extended class `Shapes` and implicitly it extends class `Object`. I know no other extension is possible, but can't we call inherited classes `Shapes` and `Object` multiple inheritance? (Since inheriting two classes is multiple inheritance from one perspective)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452461/inheritance-in-java-and-superclassesobject-class

Comment: Multiple inheritance is when a single class inherits directly from two or more classes in one instance (not through it's ancestor).  It would be like trying to do `public class Rectangle extends Shape, Point, Dimension` - which Java obviously can't do.

Comment: s/implicitly/indirectly/  :P  The `Object` inheritance is from `Shapes` extending `Object`.  (Every class, except `Object`, inherits from exactly one base class.  If you don't specify the base class, it defaults to `Object`.)  If there's a difference between `Shapes` and `Object`, `Rectangle` will always see the `Shapes` version.

Comment: Please correct your knowledge on Multiple Inheritance. What you are referring in the question is Multi-level Inheritance its not Multiple Inheritance.

Answer (score 10):

It isnt multiple inheritance. You are not inheriting from `Shapes` and `Object`, you are **inheriting from `Shapes` which is an `Object`**.

Multiple inheritance is only if you inherit from 2 classes at once.

```
public class Rectangle extends Shapes, Figures
```

Which isnt allowed in Java.

What you are referring to is [Multilevel Inheritance](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/16638.html). Thanks @BhavikShah

Comment: Agreed. I believe the fact that Rectacle extends Shapes and Shapes extends Object is called transitive inheritance.

Comment: @gerrytan : I believe its called multilevel inheritance

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the definition of *single* inheritance.  A class inherits the attributes and methods of its superclass, and all of the superclass' superclasses.  There is only one single path back to the root (`Object`).  In multiple inheritance there would be more than one path back to the root (or even multiple roots).

Answer (score 1):

This is not like that `Rectangle` is derived from both `Shapes` and `Object`. But `Rectangle` is derived from `Shapes` and Shapes are derived from `Object`, therefore `Rectangle` is `Shape` as well as `Object`.

```
 Object
   |
   V
 Shapes
   |
   V
Rectangle
```

Therefore there is no Multiple Inheritance in Java

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance means and it is impossible in java

```
public class A extends B, C {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is not possible in java directly.

However you can achieve this  (to certain extent) using interfaces.

e.g.

```
interface A{

 void m1();

}
interface B{

  void m2();

}

class C implements A,B{

 // it has both m1 and m2;

}
```